# how to create table row as select option

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a select menu option form SQL table with two condition 
one is table id base where no userid and second is userid base.

```
include '../conn.php';
    $userid=$_SESSION['currentid'];
$sql = "SELECT wname FROM bankw where UserId='$userid' INNER JOIN bankw where id='1' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "<select class='form-control' id='item' name='item'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['wname'] ."'>" . $row['wname'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Both are show in same option menu but my code does not show any option or show only userid base option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change and i got which i needed

```
    $userid=$_SESSION['currentid'];
$sql = "SELECT wname FROM bankw where UserId='$userid' or id='1' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "<select class='form-control' id='item' name='item'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['wname'] ."'>" . $row['wname'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Thanks all